# Is there any way to load a master page from outside the current application?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm prototyping an environment where multiple applications run on the same server, but they all share a master page.

Is it possible to load a master page from another application?  In one of my applications, I have this code:

```
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);
        this.MasterPageFile = "~/../MasterPages/Root.master";
    }
```

What this does is set the master page to a file sitting outside my current application.  (Note the ".." after the tilde -- so I'm going to the root of my current app, then stepping up a directory to find a master page.)

ASP is displeased with this:

```
The virtual path '/MasterPages/Root.master' maps to another application, which is not allowed.
```

I understand that it might be stressed out about the fact that there's no backing class for it, but what if I have nothing in the code-behind, and I choose not to inherit my master page from anything -- so the entire thing is contained in the ".master" file?

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thinking of the cuff but what if you create a virtual directory under each application which maps to the same physical directory:

```
 protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
 {
        base.OnPreInit(e);
        this.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPages/Root.master";
 }
```

So you might have a physical layout of:

> c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MasterPages
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App1
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App2

You'd then have IIS set up like:

> root\App1
>   root\App1\MasterPages
>   root\App2
>   root\App2\MasterPages

Comment: Two answer were correct.  Marking this one strictly for the depth of response.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider mapping a virtual directory into your apps folder structure, then that directory can be mapped to multiple applications at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

We made our master page very generic.  Each master page would use a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to capture our common horseshoe html (or .aspx) page.

The hardest thing about this approach is we had to put markers in the horseshoe.  These markers would indicate what the application could replace and where to place its content.

Comment: I've tried exactly what you're suggesting.  It was a huge pain for us.

Comment: It was a big pain for us at first but once we put the process in place, it made it seemless to add/update to an application. Since our horsehoe has a mandated look & feel to it, it's probably the best way, (and as the app developer, you won't have to worry about creating the horseshoe & if it hits the mandate).